# Eclipse AVD Not Seeing Connected Devices - Win 8

Tags: android, eclipse

When I connect an external device through USB it does not appear in the ADVM

I was previously using Eclipse on a 32bit Win 7 build and had no problems, when a device was connected it appeared in the ADVM.

I have since clean installed the machine with 64bit Win 8 and installed Eclipse and the SDKs from scratch.

When I connect a device LogCat records a load of information about the device and what it is doing. but when I open ADVM the device is not present so I can't use it as the run target.

Any ideas?

(I am a dabbler writing silly apps for my kids devices not a fully fledged coder)

Comment: Try running `adb devices`. Do you see your device in the list?

Comment: Yeah, I was being a complete Numpty, I was using Eclipse from memory and forgotten that the AVDM doesn't list connected devices, they are listed at run in the ADC. Idiot

Answer (score 0):

What is happening to me is that the *name* of the device is not being shown, but it will still be the first device when it asks me to choose. Try clicking on the first list item in the "running devices" when you have to pick which one to launch from. If you can pick it (it'll be a blank item), and Run, it should/might work.Try it out, it's exactly what's happening to me. I suspect this could be it just because your LogCat seems to be working.